# Opening Bash on Windows on a specific folder

Tags: windows, bash

I started using bash on the Windows anniversary update and recently I tried to start an Android project but want to open the terminal on the project folder. I tried googling this but couldn't find any solutions that allowed for this through command line.

Comment: As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), there is no way to invoke _Windows_ executables from the Bash environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to set a default folder so I just created a script that would cd into the right folder and ran that every time I opened bash